# Using pjsip in Java with JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, pjsip

I am trying to use PJSIP in my own standalone Java application, but I am facing a lot of issues in building the DLLs for Java.
Is there any DOCs for doing this as I am new to JNI so any help ?

This is the error I am getting when I try to load ("libpjsua.so")

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libpjsua.so.2: libpjsip-ua.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```java
public class Main {
    static {
        try {
            System.load("/home/sip/libpjsua2.so");
            System.out.println("Loaded");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        Call call = new Call(null, 0);
        System.out.println("this is call: "+call);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
and this is the result of running `ldd /home/sip/libpjsua2.so`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffee372b000)
    libpjsua.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjsua.so.2 (0x00007fdab1d55000)
    libpjsip-simple.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjsip-simple.so.2 (0x00007fdab1d3c000)
    libpjsip.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjsip.so.2 (0x00007fdab1ce3000)
    libpjmedia.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjmedia.so.2 (0x00007fdab1c7b000)
    libpjlib-util.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjlib-util.so.2 (0x00007fdab1c4f000)
    libpj.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpj.so.2 (0x00007fdab1c13000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdab19d3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdab19b3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdab178b000)
    libpjsip-ua.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjsip-ua.so.2 (0x00007fdab176b000)
    libpjmedia-audiodev.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjmedia-audiodev.so.2 (0x00007fdab1761000)
    libpjmedia-codec.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjmedia-codec.so.2 (0x00007fdab174f000)
    libpjnath.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libpjnath.so.2 (0x00007fdab1719000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007fdab12d7000)
    libsrtp.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libsrtp.so.2 (0x00007fdab12c1000)
    libresample.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libresample.so.2 (0x00007fdab12b2000)
    libspeex.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libspeex.so.2 (0x00007fdab1282000)
    libwebrtc.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libwebrtc.so.2 (0x00007fdab1257000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdab1170000)
    libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x00007fdab10cc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdab1f0e000)
    libasound.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007fdab0fc9000)
    libgsmcodec.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libgsmcodec.so.2 (0x00007fdab0fbd000)
    libilbccodec.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libilbccodec.so.2 (0x00007fdab0faa000)
```

Comment: `libpjsip-ua.so.2` needs to be present in your PATH or LIBPATH. But there is at least one Java implementation of SIP, I've used it myself.

Comment: it's present in my path, but still the same error shows up

Comment: Add `/home/sip` to your `LIBPATH`, and put this DLL there along with your JNI DLL, and use `System.loadLibrary("pjsua2.so")`.

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace()` to the `catch` block (before `System.exit(1)`, of-course).

Comment: @Abra Well yeah, in general, but we already know it comes from the line that loads the library.

Comment: @user207421 the stack trace may hold other, relevant information apart from the line that is throwing the error. I believe one should get into the habit of recording the stack trace in almost every `catch` block. Note that _recording the stack trace_ does not necessarily mean calling method `printStackTrace()`

Comment: @Abra it will not. dependency libraries are handled by the OS library loader which does not contribute to Java stack traces.

Comment: It seems you are on Linux Then the correct variable to set is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. As a debugging tool, you should be able to run `ldd /home/sip/libpjsua2.so` and have it come up without any "not found" entries.

Comment: @Botje I ran the command and didn't get any errors

Comment: No lines with "not found" in, then? Are you running Java in the same environment?

Comment: No it's all fine I'll edit the question to add the result
and yes I am running java in the same env